# Vue router changes the url after page reload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I have a problem with vue router when I reload the page.

The link http://example.com/admin/home/page1

changes to this

http://example.com/admin/home/page1/page1 .

## NB : this project is in laravel's public directory

vue version 3.9.2
os win 10 x64

router.js

````
const router = new Router({
mode: ‘history’,
base: process.env.VUE_APP_LINK,
routes: [
{
path: ‘/home’,
name: ‘home’,
component: Home,
children: [
{
path: ‘page1’,
name: ‘page1’,
component: () => import(’@/components/contents/page1.vue’),
},
{
path: ‘page2’,
name: ‘page2’,
component: () => import(’@/components/tools/page2.vue’),
},
{
path: ‘page3’,
name: ‘page3’,
component: () => import(’@/components/contents/page3.vue’),
},
{
path: ‘page4’,
name: ‘page4’,
component: () => import(’@/components/contents/page4.vue’),
}]},
{
path: ‘/login’,
name: ‘login’,
component: Login
},
{
 path: '*',
 redirect: '/home/page1'
}
]
})```

<li class="nav-item"><router-link to="page1" class="nav-link">page1</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="page2" class="nav-link">page2</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="page3" class="nav-link">page3</router-link></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><router-link to="page4" class="nav-link">page4</router-link></li>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `/page1` or `/home/page1` instead of `page1` in your `path` values.